# How to add and make sure there's one space after every <p> and before </p>

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am comparing string and displaying differences. These text string might have tags. Problematic situation is when two tags are not separated with a space, example:

`<p>Some random text</p>` is compared to `<p><strong>Some random</strong> text</p>`. In this case diff algorithm thinks that 1st diff is `<p>Some` and `<p><strong>Some` and to show it, it does something like this:

`<del><p><Some></del><ins><p><strong>Some</ins> <del>random</del> <ins>random</strong></ins> text</p>` (del - deleted, ins - inserted)

I bet you see where I'm going - it duplicated `<p>`, while there's one `</p>`.

To fix this issue, I have to make sure there's one space after each `<p>` and before each `</p>` so it doesn't see it as difference (I need this fix only for `p` tags). But space must be added only if there is no spacebar, because this text string might be updated, so If I add a space each time this string is updated, it would accumulated and that's bad.

tl;dr; Any idea how to check if there's space after `<p>` and before `</p>` and if no, add one space. And do this procedure for all tags in the `$string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(`<del><p>` is not valid markup as `<del>` is an inline element but `<p>` is a block-level elements, inline elements cannot contain block-level elements).

Your underlying issue would be better solved with an XML-aware diffing algorithm rather than your current whitespace-sensitive text-only diff. However I am sensitive to the need for a quick-fix, so this looks like a suitable use-case for Regular Expressions.

(Before the "Don't use Regex with HTML" crowd speak up: while regex indeed cannot be used to intelligently parse HTML, you can still appropriately use it to perform simple text processing operations that don't rely-upon nor alter the semantic structure of the document).

```
$text = "<p> hasSpace </p>\r\n<p>noSpace</p>";
$text = preg_replace( "/<p>([\S])/" , "<p> ${1}" , $text ); // Ensure all <p> has trailing space
$text = preg_replace( "/([\S])</p>/", "${1} </p>", $text ); // Ensure all </p> has leading space
echo "<pre>$text</pre>";
```

This gives this output:

```
<p> hasSpace </p>
<p> noSpace </p>
```

Comment: There's no problem with <del><p> if <p> has space, because it becomes excluded from difference, so <del> will always be after <p> and </del> before </p>.
And I see no problem in using this diff algorithm, because other allowed html must stay near words, because the difference is color coded. If diff is <strong> with spaces from both sides, <ins><strong></inds> wouldn't catch and color code because theres no actual word between ins.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a brute force replacement for `<p>` and `</p>` this will do it for you:

```
$string=str_replace(array("<p>","</p>"),array("<p> "," </p>"),$string);
```

[Heres some example code](http://codepad.org/YYnGswBj):

```
$string ="<p><strong>Some random</strong> text</p>";
echo $string;
echo "\n";

$string=str_replace(array("<p>","</p>"),array("<p> "," </p>"),$string);
echo $string;
```

Which outputs:

```
<p><strong>Some random</strong> text</p>
<p> <strong>Some random</strong> text </p>
```

Comment: Running str_replace like this twice would double the space. That's one of issues I was referring.